# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null with angular2-polyfills.js and arcGis init.js

Tags: angular, arcgis

I am using Angular 2 Framework and ArcGis to display the map.

I am getting the following Exception in Chrome console

```
angular2-polyfills.js:1250
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
b.get @ init.js:143
e.constructor @ init.js:343
(anonymous function) @ init.js:98
(anonymous function) @ arcGis.js:45
ha @ init.js:22
(anonymous function) @ init.js:23
ia @ init.js:23
fa @ init.js:23
g @ init.js:25
(anonymous function) @ init.js:30
Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243
zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220
```

I can clearly see that there is some issue with angular2-polfills.js and ArcGis init.js. Please help me in fixing the issue

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <script src="https://rawgithub.com/systemjs/systemjs/0.19.6/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.34.4/es6-shim.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/Rx.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-all.umd.js"></script>

   </head>
<body >
<div class="container">

     <my-app>

     <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" 
       data-dojo-props="design:'headline', gutters:false" 
       style="width:100%;height:100%;margin:0px;">

    <div id="map" 
         data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" 
         data-dojo-props="region:'center'" class="panel">
    </div>


    </div>
 </div>
 </my-app>
   </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.16/"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/arcGis.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
  (function(app) {
  app.MyApp= ng.core
    .Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: ''
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: function() {}
    });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));


(function(app) {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(app.MyApp);
  });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

Comment: Try to move socket.io script before js.arcgis.com/3.16. It seems that socket.io is trying to define the global function define when it already exists, creating a conflict.

Comment: I did this. the error is gone but getting another error 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of nullb.get @ init.js:143e.constructor @ init.js:343(anonymous function) @ init.js:98(anonymous function) @ arcGis.js:45ha @ init.js:22(anonymous function) @ init.js:23ia @ init.js:23fa @ init.js:23g @ init.js:25(anonymous function) @ init.js:30Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220

Comment: I have edited the code. Can you please check it?

Comment: Where can i see the file js/arcGis.js?